# Unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

This script is supposed to retrieve the CustomerID for the Customer_First_Name and Customer_Last_Name that has been entered into a form.

```
$query  = "SELECT CustomerID FROM customer WHERE Customer_First_Name = `.$db_customer_first_name.` AND Customer_Last_Name = `.$db_customer_last_name.`";
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
echo $result;
echo $query;
```

when the script runs I get this error:

> Unknown column '.Christopher.' in 'where clause'

the query is never printed on the screen.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are bad use ' instead of the tick `

Answer (score 0):

Use `'` instead of remove **`**

```
$query  = "SELECT CustomerID FROM customer WHERE Customer_First_Name = '".$db_customer_first_name."' AND Customer_Last_Name = '".$db_customer_last_name."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quotes for strings. Try again:

```
$query  = "SELECT CustomerID FROM customer WHERE Customer_First_Name = '".$db_customer_first_name."' AND Customer_Last_Name = '".$db_customer_last_name."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$query  = "SELECT CustomerID FROM customer WHERE Customer_First_Name = '$db_customer_first_name' AND Customer_Last_Name = '$db_customer_last_name'";
```

You need to use normal single quotes for values.  Also you don't need to break the string if you're using double quotes - variables are detected within the string.

Make sure you're also correctly escaping your strings for mysql to prevent injection.

Better still, look at moving to mysqli and using prepared statements.